# Redirection not working in meteor router

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I need to redirect from a router function to another.My router code is

```
'/url1' : function()
{
  Meteor.Router.to('/url1');

},
'/url2' : function()
{   
   return 'templatename';
}
```

What I'm trying is, when a user types example.com/url1, it should be redirected to example.com/url2.
But what I can see is just a 'null' in the screen.
How can this be done ?

Comment: Do you have any reasons why you are using meteor-router? This package is deprecated. You should use iron-router instead.

Answer (score 0):

Agree you should use iron-router.  In iron router, you'd just use the Router.go('/url2'); line to get the behavior you want.